# errors in installing mysql-server on my ubuntu machine

Tags: mysql

My problem is, I am not able to install MySQL-server on my Ubuntu linux os. I tried this line

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

on the terminal. It shows the below error. Even I used the line

```
sudo apt autoremove mysql-server
```

I got the same error.

The error will be encountered while processing

```
oracle-java8-installer
default-jre-headless
default-jre
E-sub-process user/bin/dpkg returned an error code(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

do

```
dpkg --configure -a
```

then try

```
sudo apt remove --purge mysql-server

sudo apt install mariadb-server
sudo apt install mariadb-client
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```